# The terminology of a set and subset of a simple number in base 2

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, binary

Im trying to understand the basics of sets and subsets in Set Theory in relations to binary (base-2) computation (not to be confused with binary relations which I do not know anything about).

Lets say I have a binary string of length *n* = 9. i.e. a binary number. *n* could be anything, but I just use this as an example.

If A is a set of only one binary number. Or where the set of {0, 1} are the elements.

Can one define a subset of a bitstring like this:

[image]

And how would one go about writing this in math notation?

What can I call sets, and subsets?
Is the binary string of length *n*-1 (with copies from the original string excluding one bit) a subset?

My question regards finite bitstring of length *n*. And what its terminology are to Set Theory if one take an arbitrary substring of that string.

Thank you.

Comment: There is no such thing as a subset of a bit string.  The example you illustrated is a substring.

Comment: I said it was a substring in the preamble of my question. I ask how is that substring represented as a subset of a larger set?

Comment: No................

Comment: The only way is to represent the string $S_8$ of lenght eight as a set $\{ a_0,a_1, \ldots, a_7 \}$, where $a_i \in \{ 0,1 \}$ for each $i$. In this way a substring can be $\{ a_4,a_5 \}$.

Comment: Thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA. Is that substring: $\{a_4, a_5\}$ a subset of that set or is a subset something completely different?

Comment: Yes; as sets: $\{ a_4,a_5 \} \subseteq \{ a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6, a_7 \}$.